# How to remove element from DOM after class has been added

Tags: jquery, sizzle

This is using Sizzle/jQuery. I'm trying to remove an element (.offers-detail) from the DOM *after* adding a class to animate it's 'removal' from the GUI. In short, I have a series of divs listed vertically. Each .offers-detail div has a 'remove' button. When the remove button is clicked, I use jQuery to check the number of .offers-detail divs remaining and do something based on that number. After those checks are performed and executed, I want to addClass and animate the height of the div to 0 (zero) and then I'd like the offers-detail div that contained the remove button that was clicked to be removed from the DOM completely.

I've been able to run the checks or animate the div to zero height, but not execute the checks and remove it from the DOM. If I just use .remove, the parent div is removed from the DOM but I cannot get them to work together. Below is just one example of what I've tried - .delay() and then .remove(). This generates an error saying "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"

Any help is appreciated.

```
$(".icon").on("click", function () {
        var numOffers = $( '.offers-detail' ).length;

        $(this).closest('.offers-detail').addClass('active').delay(500).remove();

        // Show alert if max (5) number of offers entered
        if (numOffers == 5) {
            $('span.offers-alert').show();

        // Hide alert if more than 1 and less than 5
        } else if (numOffers >= 1 && numOffers <= 4) {
            $('span.offers-alert').hide();
            // Show offer code text input
            $('.offer-code').show();

            // Change verbiage if no offer codes present/entered
        } else if (numOffers == 0) {
            $('h4.applied-codes').replaceWith('no offer codes entered');
            $('.offer-code').show();
        } 
});
```

Here is the HTML

```
<div class="offers-detail-max">
    <span class="offers-alert"><h4 class="red"><span class="icon red">alert</span> You've reached your max number of offers.</h4></span>
    <h4 class="applied-codes">applied offer codes</h4>

    <div class="offers-detail">
        <div class="gray-bg">
            <div class="description">
                <h4>shoe lover</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="amount">
                <h4>-$5.00 <span class="icon red">remove-circle</span></h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="offers-detail">
        <div class="gray-bg">
            <div class="description">
                <h4>vet's day</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="amount">
                <h4>-$5.00 <span class="icon red">remove-circle</span></h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="offers-detail">
        <div class="gray-bg">
            <div class="description">
                <h4>flower power</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="amount">
                <h4>-$5.00 <span class="icon red">remove-circle</span></h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="offers-detail">
        <div class="gray-bg">
            <div class="description">
                <h4>black friday</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="amount">
                <h4>-$5.00 <span class="icon red">remove-circle</span></h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="offers-detail">
        <div class="gray-bg">
            <div class="description">
                <h4>new years</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="amount">
                <h4>-$5.00 <span class="icon red">remove-circle</span></h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<div class="offer-code">
    <h4>enter an offer code</h4>
    <input class="offercode" type="text" placeholder="Enter one code at a time" />
    <input class="primary" type="button" value="submit" />
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your example didn't generate any errors for me: http://jsfiddle.net/553hajj0/2/.

Comment: Apologies. This version doesn't error but it also doesn't work as intended/desired. It removes the element from the DOM but it doesn't delay and it doesn't animate. The delay isn't necessary but it definitely needs to animate before removing from the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use setTimeout in your case, replacing this line:

```
$(this).closest('.offers-detail').addClass('active').delay(500).remove();
```

for these ones:

```
var $item = $(this).parents('.offers-detail');
$item.addClass('active');

setTimeout(function() { $item.remove(); }, 5000);
```

In this way, it adds the class, wait 5 seconds and then remove the element.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/553hajj0/3/

Give it a try and let me know if it helps!

Comment: That did it! There's some other bugginess that I'm pretty sure I can address but now it animates and removes. That was the main goal. THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.className').remove();
```

.remove() removes the element specified from the DOM

EDIT:
change script to

```
$(".icon").on("click", function () {
    var numOffers = $( '.offers-detail' ).length;
    $(this).closest('.offers-detail').addClass('active').remove();
    numOffers = $( '.offers-detail' ).length;
    // Show alert if max (5) number of offers entered
    if (numOffers == 5) {
        $('span.offers-alert').show();

    // Hide alert if more than 1 and less than 5
    } else if (numOffers >= 1 && numOffers <= 4) {
        $('span.offers-alert').hide();
        // Show offer code text input
        $('.offer-code').show();

        // Change verbiage if no offer codes present/entered
    } else if (numOffers == 0) {
        $('h4.applied-codes').replaceWith('no offer codes entered');
        $('.offer-code').show();
    } 
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm not trying to remove the class, I'm trying to remove the entire div from the DOM. I've tried `.remove` after adding the class that creates the animation, but it does not work.

Comment: I think you misunderstood, .remove() does not remove class, but the entire div to which that class is applied. for removing class there is .removeClass(). in the reply you are missing parenthesis --> (). use ,remove() properly, it will work.

Comment: You are correct, I did misunderstand. However, the problem is removing the element from the dom *after* the addClass has been applied and the other if/else statements are executed. Using `.remove` at this point causes an error. As you can see from the sample code above, I tried to add the class, delay for .5 seconds and then remove. This does not work. My latest effort is to `setTimeout` then check for `hasClass` and if it does, `.remove`. It also generates an error in the inspector. "undefined is not a function".

Comment: can you provide html for more clarity

Comment: okay, i got your problem, the thing is you are initializing the numOffers before removal of element from the DOM, and checking condition after removal, please check http://jsfiddle.net/7kmxmqam/ , i hope this solves your problem, editing the answer now.

Comment: Thanks again, Chaitanya. Your fix works *except* the animation doesn't occur after the class 'active' is added. Thinking that it needs a slight delay between `.addClass('active')` and `.remove()`, I added `.delay(500)` so it looks like this: `.addClass('active').delay(500).remove();` but that generates an error "undefined is not a function" and highlights `.delay()` in Inspector.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add a short setTimeout per Everton Lenger's answer above. This allowed the animation to take place and then the div to be removed from the DOM.